# Random variable representing multiple values of another following exponential distribution

Tags: probability

I have $t \sim \varepsilon(\lambda)$. Then if I let $X$ represent the sequence of occurrence of $t$ like: $t_1+t_2+t_3+...+t_n$ does $X \sim \mathcal{G}(n, \lambda)$? Since I know that when $X \sim \mathcal{G}(1, \lambda)$ then $X \sim \varepsilon(\lambda)$?

---

Reason I ask this is because in an attempt to do question below (part (b ii) in particular)

[image]

My first impression is its asking the time to the *start* of the nth service. But if the previous part seem to be more useful if its until the end of the nth service?

If $T_n$ is referring to time until the start it will look like:

- $T_1 = \tau$
- $T_2 = 2 \tau + t_1$
- $T_n = n \tau + \underbrace{t_1 + ... + t_{n-1}}_{X}$

Versus if its referring to time until end of service

- $T_1 = \tau + t_1$
- $T_2 = 2 \tau + t_1 + t_2$
- $T_n = n \tau + \underbrace{t_1 + ... + t_{n}}_{X}$

Either way if I let the end portion be the random variable $X$ then I can reuse my answer for part (b i)? If each of those $t_i$ follows the exponential distribution, can I say $X$ follows a gamma distribution? Or am I supposed to do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gamma distribution satisfies the following property: $A_i \sim \mathcal{G}(\alpha_i, \beta), i =1,2, \cdots, n \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i \sim \mathcal{G}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i , \beta)$.

Comment: Err ... so is the answer yes? That if I have $\sum_i t_i$ where each $t_i \sim \varepsilon(\lambda)$ then $\sum_i t_i \sim \mathcal{G}(n, \lambda)$. In this statement, 1st parameter of gamma distribution is $\mathbb{Z}^+$ but in your case, is it the same for $\alpha_i$?

Comment: @JiewMeng Yes, it is. We only need that these Gamma distributions in the sum are independent between each other. The parameters $\alpha_i$ can be any positive numbers